# [Solved]Showing that a sequence converges to zero (Aitken's extrapolation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, nonlinear-optimization

So here's the problem:

let $g:[a,b]\to[a,b]$ be a $C^1$ function such that: $$\forall x\in [a,b],|g'(x)|<1$$ We proved that this function has a unique fixed point in the given interval and we constructed a sequence that converges to this fixed point $\alpha$;
for any arbitrary $x_0\in[a,b]$ we define $x_{n+1}=g(x_n),  \forall n>0$

We also proved that there exists a sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $$e_{n+1}=(g'(\alpha)+\epsilon_n)e_n \\\lim_{n\to \infty}\epsilon_n = 0\\e_n=x_n-\alpha$$
then we define this sequence: $$y_n=x_n - {(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2 \over x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}+x_n}$$ we are asked to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{y_n-\alpha \over x_n-\alpha}=0$$

*I may have committed a mistake while doing the calculations (few attempts), I couldn't prove that it goes to zero. (sorry if the formatting isn't that clear)*

Comment: Please define $e_n$ *before* you use it to define $\epsilon_n$, not after!

Comment: Have recognized that the denominator of $y_n$ is $(x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}) - (x_{n+1} - x_n)$? That is, the second difference of the $x_n$ sequence.

Comment: sorry for that. Yes I noticed that, then i tried to add and substract alpha so that i can work with $e_n$ instead but i couldn't figure out where my mistake is. I'll give it another try today otherwise i will ask my teacher for direct help. Thanks for replying sir!

Comment: I found the solution, i was not careful the last time. Thanks again! :)